# vue chat app doesnt show data after mount

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm messing around with a few vue chat libraries and I have this code:

```
<template>
    <p>{{ this.users[0] }}</p>
</template>


<script>
export default {

  data() {
    return {
      users: []
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    firestoreService.getAllUsers().then(({ data }) => {
      data.forEach((user, i) => {
        this.users[i] = user
      });
    })
  }
</script>
```

Basically I have a firestore index where I store my users and on mount hook I populate the users array but for some reason vue does not see the data. Any ideas?

If I `console.log` the data I can see the data in the console.

Comment: can you confirm that `data.forEach` callback is running? also, please add vuejs2 or vuejs3 tag as appropriate - also, you should be able to do just `this.users = data`

Comment: nevermind ... I see the issue do `<p>{{ users[0] }}</p>`, you don't need `this` in the template - however `this.users = data` is all you need

Comment: don't use ```this``` in template just use {{ users[0] }}

Comment: its the same without the ```this```, i am using vue 2.6

Comment: confirm that `this.users[i] = user` is run at least once - i.e. `console.log(user)` in that `.forEach` and *check your browser developer tools console*

Comment: just changed to ```this.users = data``` and it worked... Thanks! although, why doesn't it run with the foreach? The foreach is working I am seeing every iteration

Comment: the mysteries of vue!!

Comment: @JaromandaX There's no mystery. The reactivity isn't triggered in V2 for direct array index access.

Comment: @EstusFlask ... today I learned a new thing. Thanks

Comment: this is so typical for js

Answer (score 0):

The assignments of array elements by index are [not reactive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays) in Vue 2. The reactivity can be triggered by the use of `Vue.set`, or array methods like `push`, e.g.:

```
  data.forEach((user, i) => {
    Vue.set(this.users, i, user);
  });
```

Since an array needs to be fully replaced, a correct way is to replace the whole array with the result, as it has been already suggested in comments:

```
firestoreService.getAllUsers().then(({ data }) => {
  this.users = data
})
```